# xpages how to force a partial refresh afterPageLoad

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, partial-page-refresh

I asked this question a couple months ago, but there has been no response so I thought I would try again. I have a block of SSJS that manipulates a number of values. There are some computed fields that are impacted by these changes and they do not display correctly. I have a refresh button on the XPage and it does a partial refresh after which everything works fine. I need to somehow trigger a partial refresh on the a specific item (a panel in this case) as the last step in the afterPageLoad in the SSJS. 
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your SSJS running and what values is it changing?

Answer (score 3):

Refreshing Panels from SSJS without a button, link or something like that is a bit tricky.

But i think your problem is more located in the order in wich you are trying to compute your fields what about triggering your Code in a erlier event before those Fields are rendered, to avoid displaying the wrong values in the first place, maby post some example Code.

If you only want to refresh a the panel again after the page has bean loaded try this in the onClientLoad ClientEvent this could also fix it:

```
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.ready(function(){
    XSP.partialRefreshGet('#{id:yourPanel}',{})

});]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: My problem is that I load a bunch of values into controls on the page during the beforePageLoad event (tried the afterPageLoad with the same result) from a profile document that it looks up - this all works correctly. I have buttons on the XPage the are rendered or not based on values that are loaded from the profile document. But the buttons do not render properly until I do a manual refresh of panelAll from a button. From that point on everything works well. So as you say I think the issue has to do with the sequence of events.